# Using Codesite with Record Types

Tags: delphi, object, dynamic, creation

In Delphi XE, I would like to use codesite to generate information regarding a record type.  I know it is possible to force records to [emit RTTI](http://alex.ciobanu.org/?p=55), but I am wondering if there is a way to inturn use this information to use Codesight's .send method?

eg, CodeSite.send('Hello World', self); works because self is a TObject.  but this won't work if self is a record type.

What I am trying to do may not be possible, but I thought I would take a chance anyway.  What I really would like to do is dynamically convert record types into simple objects.  Then I could pass this object into the call above.

Comment: Hi, sse.  Interesting question. Have you asked Ray at Raize, the author of CodeSite?  He'd probably be the best source of information on this.

Comment: There's an example of sending all record data (in a couple of formats) via `Send` in the CodeSight 4 help file that's included with the XE/XE2 distribution of CS. In the `CodeSight4.chm` file (from Start->All Programs->CodeSight 4-> CodeSight Help`), look at `Advanced Techniques->Sending Custom Data->TCodeSiteFormatter (Delphi)`. (Change CS 4 to CS 5 for XE2.)

Comment: @KenWhite thanks for the reference.  Unfortunately this is not quite what I am looking for.  It requires that I write code for each record type.  I am looking for a way to instantiate some generic object type based upon the record data, possibly using the RTTI emitted from the record itself.

Comment: OK. Wasn't sure from the phrasing of the question, so I just thought I'd mention it. (That's why it's a comment and not an answer.) The easy way, obviously, would be to convert your record to a class, which would satisfy your requirement very easily. :-)

Comment: You are right Ken, I just updated the question.  Thank you again.

Comment: I spent a large part of the evening experimenting with CS5 and XE2 (using the CS5 Express version), and can't find a way without either using a class, or upgrading to the Pro version of CS5 and using the `TCodeSiteFormatter` (which isn't supported in CS5 Express). I even tried in Delphi Prism and couldn't come up with a way. IMO, this is something that should be asked at the CodeSite forums at Raize, because it's not something that's possible according to the documentation.